# How to call DocuSign Signer Information screen?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to replicate the functionality of [this DocuSign demo](http://sedemo1.cloudapp.net/GennWatt/embedded.html), where the user may or may not enter their email address into the form. If they do not enter their email address, DocuSign brings up this screen:

[image]

However, whenever I leave the recipient's email null in my API call, this screen never comes up. How can I bring this screen up when the user doesn't submit their email?

Answer (score 1):

That demo isn't using the DocuSign API. Rather, it is using an integration method that is easier than the API, DocuSign PowerForms.

PowerForms enable you to define a web form, hosted by DocuSign. When it is filled out, a signing process starts. (So an API call is NOT made to start the signing process.)

Out of the box, PowerForms provides the sort of screen that you're showing in your question. Or your app can send parameters to the PowerForm. [Docs on pre-populating the PowerForm fields](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-populate-custom-document-fields-in-a-web-powerform).

If your app wants immediate notification of when the PowerForm-created signing request has been signed by someone, use Connect. [See related SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417000/docusign-powerforms-embed-success-status)

Google for DocuSign Powerforms to see additional information and docs.

You can easily try out PowerForms, they're part of the [free DocuSign Dev Sandbox](https://secure.docusign.com/signup/developer). Note that not all DocuSign account types include the PowerForms feature, contact DocuSign sales for more info.